# Is it possible to launch the Windows command prompt from Management Console?

Tags: windows, command-line-interface

I've googled for this quite a bit - I have a custom MMC setup at work that gives me quick access to everything I need, including various web-based admin consoles. The one thing I can't seem to do is embed the Windows command prompt (regular cmd.exe or PowerShell) in MMC. Is this doable?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot snap in something that is not a management console to the management console framework.

Is `Win`+`r` cmd `ENTER` very difficult to use? or are you just trying to have easier window management?

Comment: I'm really just looking for easier window management. I find it really convenient to have everything in MMC on the computer in question - it's not my main machine...it's just an admin machine that I use to do certain tasks. I was hoping there was an MMC plugin of some kind that allowed loading a command window.